# OAuth 2.0 Flow with Firebase Functions

Tags: firebase, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-functions

How do I use Firebase Functions to successfully connect to an OAuth 2.0 app (ex: [Alpaca](https://alpaca.markets/docs/build-apps_services-with-alpaca/oauth-guide/))? The closest I've found is this [GCP tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-functions-oauth-gmail) but it doesn't save the access token for future use.

How do I:

1. Remember the state (random string used to protect against request forgery attacks) across different Firestore Functions so I can determine whether it's unchanged?
2. Associate the access token with the user that authorized me (ideally saving the token in Firestore)?

Is there a library that does all this for me that will work from a Firebase Function?

Comment: If you think my answer helped you, please, consider upvoting, accepting it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed a lot of the instructions from [this guide](https://medium.com/better-programming/building-secure-login-flow-with-oauth-2-openid-in-react-apps-ce6e8e29630a). Here are the answers to my original questions for posterity:

1. (Remembering state) Generate it on the client side and save somewhere (I used localStorage). Pass the state to a Firebase function that generates your authorization url and returns it to the client.
2. (Saving access token) After authorization I redirect back to the client side (as opposed to a Firebase function). From the client I parse the auth code and check if state matches. I pass the authorization code to a Firebase Function to configure the request for the final access token. Since I called the function from the client I have access to the `context` param that tells me the `uid` associated with the access token.

Comment: Thanks for answering. This helps with the problem of cookies being no longer cross site (function generating the state)

Answer (score 2):

For you to connect OAuth 2.0 to Cloud Functions, indeed, the documentation you provided, would be the official one, to achieve that. And I understand your points, about your questions, of remembering state and associating the token with the access, it actually would be very helpful.

To answer your question, there isn't a library that does all of this for you. Searching around, it seems that you can use a JWT token, which would provide you some options of predefined fields, that might help you have more control to the expiration time, who the token is intended to, etc. In case you are interested on it, there is a good documentation about how to use it with Cloud Functions here: [Understanding OAuth2 and Deploying a Basic Authorization Service to Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/understanding-oauth2-and-deploy-a-basic-auth-srv-to-cloud-functions)

Outside of that, unfortunately, it doesn't seem that you have other options. For this reason, I would recommend you also to raise a Feature Request in [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187195&template=0), so they can take a look about the possibility of changing/improving the way that the OAuth 2.0 works with Cloud Functions in the future.

Let me know if the information helped you!